# Carry Detection in summation

Tags: sum, logic

I want to check whether the two numbers when added, generate a carry or not.
I assume both numbers are in range 0-9.

Our constraints :

1. we can not use any operations whose result may goes above 9 or below 0.
2. we can not use any number out of range 0-9.
3. we can not use any floating point operation or number.

For example, I can not use `if (a+b > 9) then print("there is a carry.");`
as, as if `a=9` and `b=6` then `a+b = 15`. and 15 is out of range.

Is there any efficient way?
If there is, answer that efficient way to check the carry in summation. (do consider the constraints as above)

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, that's ok... it's just courteous to disclose that.

Comment: a one line answer rarely can b any homework.. it is certainly not a homework.. it was a simple question just came in mind.. when i was going through some questions based on overflow in integers..

Comment: @Matthew Specifying that it's homework is not constructive (which is exactly why the [tag:homework] tag [is gone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)), but (@Rambo) you probably should show some attempt at solving the problem yourself, questions showing no attempt from the asker are often received *very* negatively.

Comment: @Dukeling answers to homework problems have historically been met with more exploitative answers where people assume the asker may not really understand *why* the answers apply.

Comment: Dukeling : yes i will mind to attempt solving myself before asking in future..

Comment: Is it also possible with some bitwise operators..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b = 9-b;
a = 0+a;
if (a > b) return true
```

I'm pretty sure that's the most efficient you can get.

Edit:

Line two is useless, so only two lines, no loops, and you're done. I'm not deleting the original, though, because I think it's funny I actually did that.

Comment: What is the purpose of line 2?

Comment: Mathew, I honestly have no idea.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. I'm pretty sure this is the most efficient solution

Comment: Could as well just make it `return a > 9-b` now. :)

Comment: My thoughts - Don't leave pointless data around just because you think it's funny that you wrote it. Future visitors will probably see this as a nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

in psuedo code

```
while a != 0
    if(b == 9) return true
    b++;
    a--;
end

return false;
```

Comment: -1 In this code `b` could grow larger than 9 which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one rule

```
If a >= b and b >=5 then there is a carry
```

Comment: This logic has many wholes.  I wasn't going to comment, but it became the accepted answer.  What if a = 9 and b = 4?

Comment: I think it was accepted by mistake. It's not a good answer, just an example of one rule

Answer (score 1):

Good that @Tomcat found the pattern to this, but sometimes brute force isn't too bad. If the inputs are integers in the range [0,10], one could create a 10*10 boolean lookup table. It would be interesting to benchmark the difference with doing the single subtraction, though it would probably be senseless optimization to go for the lookup table even if it's a tiny bit faster.

Comment: +1 This is probably the most efficient way for a computer to do this. No math operations, no loops... just checking for values in a set -- only 20 possibilities

Comment: Remember loading a value from memory is really a series of operations, and is slow.  Whereas addition and checks are faster.  Any looping function would only ever need 10 loops, and each single loop is likely faster than any load operation would ever be.

Comment: You could create a two dimensional array of all possible number combinations... then there is only one load and this method is then faster.  Yay hashing!

Comment: @Rambo There are, but you only need to check those that do not result in carrying. And by ordering the values, it can be reduced further.